# XSLT: Remove BOM character from string

Tags: xml, xslt, byte-order-mark

I am using an XSLT-Transformation (2.0).
The problem is the following:

In the XSLT I am checking the value of a string like this:

```
<xsl:if test="$recordValue[1] = 'I'">
```

But that statement sometimes fails, because the value of `$recordValue[1]` may contain the BOM symbol/character `"ï»¿"`.

How can I remove that BOM character from `$recordValue[1]`, so that the "if" also returns true if the variable contains the BOM character?

**UPDATE:**
These lines of code is also not working and still returning no if there is a BOM character in `$recordValue[1]`:

```
<xsl:variable name="recordValue" select="tokenize(current(), ';')" />
<xsl:variable name="prozess"     select="replace($recordValue[1], '^ï»¿', '')" />

<xsl:if test="$prozess = 'I'">
```

The relevant XML-Line, I am trying to convert is the following (which has a BOM symbol before the *'I'*):

```
<splitSegment><record>I;20.02.2018 11:58:35;02;113502190168;10;1</record></splitSegment>
```

**Alternative Solution (not fixing the problem itself):**
The following solution does **not** remove the BOM symbol, but it ensures that the relevant `if` is returning yes, even if there is a BOM symbol at the beginning of the string:

```
<xsl:if test="ends-with($prozess, 'I')">
```

Comment: How does the mangled BOM end up in the value? *This* is the error you should fix.

Comment: The user creates the import file, which contains the BOM symbol. Unfortunately the User has not the possibility to remove the BOM symbol in each of the file - is there no possibility to check/remove the BOM in XSLT?

Comment: The user does not need to remove the BOM. When your code (!) reads the file, you must read it as UTF-8, then the BOM will not show up in the data. Currently you aren't doing that. You read the file as Windows-1252. That's a bug in your code.

Comment: Also the process of reading the file is not my responsibility, because the file is read via another system (sonic esb, the configured charset there is UTF-8). That system converts the input file (txt) to a xml file, which I want to transform via xslt.

Comment: Some search results [suggest](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000032237) that SonicESB might indeed have trouble converting the UTF-8 BOM properly. If that still is the case for your version I don't know, it's worth double-checking if that part is configured correctly. However, if you are not having any trouble with extended characters - try some if you can, like German Umlauts ä, ö, ü - if they come though properly and the BOM persists, we will have to replace it in XSLT.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your research - I wasnt able to find even something like that.
I just tried using Umlaute (Ä / Ö) - they come through properly (as they are).

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 there's a `replace()` function that accepts regex. The following will replace `"ï»¿"` but only when it's at the start of the string: `replace($recordValue[1], '^ï»¿', '')`.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately this isn't working - the Output is still the same and the `if` is still returning no.

Comment: Hm... It *should* work. Please update your question with the modified line of XSLT and also include with the relevant line of XML.

Comment: There is no BOM symbol in front of the `I` in your XML, you would be able to see that.

Comment: Yeah - I am not sure, where the BOM symbol comes from. I suppose it's somewhere in a Sonic ESB process, which I am not able to look into. Because, if I just output the value of `$recordValue[1]`, it displays the BOM symbol (and also the `if` is not working) - but only for the first line in the XML.

Comment: And `<xsl:value-of select="$recordValue[2]">` does not print `ï»¿`? How about `<xsl:value-of select="current()">`? And how about `<xsl:value-of select="substring(current(), 1, 3)">`?

Comment: No - only `<xsl:value-of select="$recordValue[1]">` does print `ï»¿` (and only for the first line in the XML).
`<xsl:value-of select="current()">` prints the full line of the XML and if it's the first line of the XML, then there is `ï»¿` at the beginning.
`<xsl:value-of select="substring(current(), 1, 3)">` just prints `ï»¿` for the first line of the XML.

Comment: I don't understand all this talk of `ï»¿`. That's a sequence of three characters whose representation in iso-8859-1 is the same as the representation of a BOM in UTF-8. If you've got a BOM in the input and it renders as `ï»¿` then you're rendering it wrong, which only compounds the difficulties of diagnosis.

Comment: @MichaelDelfser So what you see is not the BOM on the *input* file, it's the BOM on the output file. And whatever method you are using to display the output file is wrong.